# Python: métodos get y set

Tags: python, get, set, metodos

Creo una clase llamada universidad, con el atributo 'nombre_de_universidad', lo inicializo y luego creo un método getter y un setter, por último creo un método para mostrar el nombre de dicha universidad, pero cuando llamo al método getter no me devuelve nada... ¿Qué está pasando? Ahí les dejo el código:

```
class Universidad():
    def __init__(self, nombreUniversidad): #Inicializo el atributo
        self._nombreUniversidad = nombreUniversidad
    
    @property #Método Getter
    def nombreUniversidad(self):
        return self._nombreUniversidad

    @nombreUniversidad.setter #Método Setter
    def nombreUniversidad(self, nombreUniversidad):
        self._nombreUniversidad = nombreUniversidad

    def mostrarUniversidad(self): #Método para mostrar el valor del atributo por su método getter
        return (nombreUniversidad)

universidad = Universidad('Stanford') #Instancio la clase
print(universidad.mostrarUniversidad())#Invoco al método
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en el método **mostrarUniversidad**. La línea **return (nombreUniversidad)** debería llamar al método getter en vez de a la variable local. Además, para llamar al método getter se debe usar la notación de punto, como en **self.nombreUniversidad**.

Por lo tanto, el método debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
def mostrarUniversidad(self):
    return (self.nombreUniversidad)
```

También es recomendable utilizar un nombre de variable con minúsculas y guiones bajos en lugar de con mayúsculas para seguir las convenciones de nombres en Python. Por ejemplo, en vez de **nombreUniversidad** se podría usar **nombre_universidad**.

Comment: Gracias por responder Cristian. Funciono bien. Entiendo lo del guion bajo, si uso 'self.nombre_universidad', no estaría llamando al atributo directamente? suponiendo que reemplaze 'nombreUniversidad'. También pensé en encapsular el atributo con doble guion bajo y quitar los métodos get y set así usar el atributo solo dentro de la misma clase.

Comment: @Leo20 ese "encapsulamiento" no es en sí un encapsulameinto, en python no existen métodos/atributos privados, todo es accesible desde fuera, solo que en python el doble guion bajo le **indica** al programador que no debe de tocar ese atributo/método, pero nada le impide cambiarlo